# Drag and Drop Multiple HTML Columns

Tags: html

I am having HTML Tables. There are 10 columns inside that table. I want to Drag and Drop more than one columns. (i.e) select multiple columns and move them around (change column ordering)

Drag and Dropping a single column i know, but how to do this with Multiple Columns...

Comment: I have personally never seen this accomplished. It sounds like poor UI to me. What's wrong with dragging them one at a time?

Comment: my client wants to select five columns and move those columns at a time...

Comment: The client is not always right. You are the field expert in this relationship. Have you tried suggesting a different approach to them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not pretty sure about the code but,
I guess there is one thing that you can try
When the user wants to move the columns then ask him to generate an event like(click on a button or something) now you know when the the particular button is clicked. Now ask the user to select the columns by clicking on them one by one when all the desired columns are selected put them in a single column and ask the user to move it. when the user drops this column on desired location you can remove this column.